# Can I query Azure Search while the index is being updated?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I need to run an Azure Search indexer to rebuild an index on > 10 million documents. If this is a long running task will the Azure Search be available to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can query an index while documents are being indexed. However, there are several things to be aware of which I mention in my [Azure Search tutorial](https://www.ecofic.com/courses/adding-search-abilities-to-your-apps-with-azure-search),

1. The document(s) will not be part of a result set until they have been indexed.
2. Indexing this many documents could potentially slow the performance of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to to query an index while documents are still being indexed.

Since the same resources will be used to index documents and to serve query traffic, you may need to add replicas to your service to maintain an acceptable level of performance. You can read more about performance and optimization of Azure Search at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization).